# How to implement authentication in WebAPI in an existing application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an existing project which is on dotnet framework 3.5 . I want to implement Web API and want to call this webAPI from javascript by using jquery.
I want to apply basic authentication and also want to use authorize the HTTP methods of WebAPI. 
Before using webAPI we are using simple authentication process by using Session variables in our application and checking the authentication and authorization process in page load method it self in the page.

Please suggest some better idea to implement the web API authentication in my application.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google brings up lots of results.

[Http Authentication using filters](http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/)

[Http Authentication using message handlers](http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/)

Or you can checkout the [webapicontrib](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib) which has examples of Http Basic Auth and more. You will possibly run into cors issues calling the api with javascript, webapicontrib has an example of a cors handler too if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Thinktecture identity library. It's so far the most complete one for ASP.NET projects, http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/